# Javascript Regular Expressions in RegEx

Tags: regex

Here's my problem. 
I want to replace all the "document 1", "document 12" strings in a text by an hypertext link :

```
<a onclick="gotodocument(document7);">document 7</a>
```

I tried this code :

```
var reg=new RegExp("((document )[a-zA-Z0-9/.]+)+\s(\w+)","gi");
var chaine= *thetext*;
  var socle_contenu = chaine.replace(reg, "<a onclick=\"alleraudocument('$1');\"'>" + '$1' + "</a>");
```

The result is :

```
 <a onclick="gotodocument(document 7);">document 7</a>
```

As you can see, the problem is the space in the onclick function.

I tried to delete this space but I want to keep this space for the human reader. I couldn't make it.

I then tried to get "document " and the number in $1 and $2, in order to contacatenate the two variables as I need. I tried this :

```
var reg=new RegExp("((document )\s(\w+))+", "gi");
```

But it doesn't work !
Can anyone tell me how to setup the regular expression ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a callback function with the replace. This allows further manipulation of the matches:

```
var s = 'document 12 some more text document 7 end';

var re = new RegExp(/(document\s?\d+)/gi);

s = s.replace(re, function($1){ 
    return "<a onclick=\"alleraudocument('" + $1.replace(' ', '') + "');\">" + $1 + "</a>";
});
```

see [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/garyh/st4ksg3v/) here

Answer (score 1):

If the part about `document` is static, you can ignore that and only match the number you need. Then create the appropriate Link:

`document\s*(\d+)` with the replacement `<a onclick="gotodocument(document$1);">document $1</a>`

https://regex101.com/r/tB5lD8/2